# Multiple input files and output the each file result in 1 line in 1 file (Hadoop:MapReduce)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am stuck in separate each file wordcount result in 1 line.
I hope to output all files result in 1 file and each file result represent in 1 line.

Expected output.txt format

```
file1 1, 2, 3, 4, …, 100
file2 5, 2, 9, 6, …, 30
```

Currently output results in 
each file wordcount result have sum up together

```
file1 123,22,31,...,100
file2 123,22,31,...,100
```

run()

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,in_path1,TextInputFormat.class,Map.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,in_path2,TextInputFormat.class,Map.class);
```

Map

```
context.write(new Text("file1"),output);
context.write(new Text("file2"),output);
```

Reduce

```
context.write(new Text("file1"),new Text(sp.toString()));
context.write(new Text("file2"),new Text(sp.toString()));
```

Map

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private static final HashMap<String, Object> counter = new HashMap<>();
        private Text output = new Text();

        private String mapToString(HashMap<String, Object> map) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, Object> entry = iter.next();
                sb.append(entry.getKey());
                sb.append('=');
                sb.append(entry.getValue().toString());

                if (iter.hasNext()) {
                    sb.append(';').append(' ');
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO: Get filename
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if (!counter.containsKey(token)) {
                    counter.put(token, 1);
                } else {
                    counter.put(token, (Integer) counter.get(token) + 1);
                }
            }
            output.set(mapToString(counter));
            context.write(new Text("filename1"), output);
        }
    }
```

Reduce

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int number = 0;
            System.out.println(key);
            for (Text val : values) { // val line record
                String[] input = val.toString().split(";\\s");
                for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                    String[] temp = input[i].split("=");
                    String topValue = temp[0];
                    topValue = temp[0].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
                    topValue = topValue.toLowerCase();

                    if (resultMap.containsKey(topValue)) {
                        int original = resultMap.get(topValue);
                        int sum = original + Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);
                        resultMap.put(topValue, sum);
                    }

                }

            }


        }

         @Override
            protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
                    InterruptedException {
             StringBuilder sp = new StringBuilder();

                System.out.println("MapSize: " + resultMap);
                int i = 0;
                Iterator iterator = resultMap.entrySet().iterator();




                while (iterator.hasNext()) {


                    Entry me2 = (Entry) iterator.next();
                    //System.out.println("key : " + me2.getKey());
                    sp.append(me2.getKey());
                    sp.append(":");
                    sp.append(me2.getValue());
                    System.out.println(me2.getValue());
                    sp.append(",");
                }

                context.write(new Text("file1"), new Text(sp.toString()));
                context.write(new Text("file2"), new Text(sp.toString()));


            }
    }
```

I am stuck in two file word count combine together. And i hope to print each file word count in 1 line.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your input and output ?

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to use `in_path1` twice?.. Please show a [mcve] of all the code.

Comment: oh, sorry is my typing mistake, the second one should be in_path2. Thanks

Comment: my input is a article. File1 is one article and file2 is another article.They contain in different txt file. And I have run the mapreduce code. But the code make their word count result combine together

Comment: If you do not want to combine the two file's output, then you create two jobs . Do you have a single or multi reducer ? Can you share the driver code.

Comment: I have tried to create an other method named Map2().And it code is same with Map(). And have change MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,in_path2,TextInputFormat.class,Map2.class);    But it still combine together.